# Strange Java regex error when matching repeated string parts

Tags: java, regex

I encountered a strange error on using Java Regular Expression recently:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("(\\d\\d)", "12"));  -->  true  
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("(\\d\\d)", "11"));  -->  true  
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("(\\d\\d)\\1", "1212"));  -->  true  
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("(\\d\\d)\\1", "1122"));  -->  false
```

What's wrong with the last one? Can anyone help me, thanks a lot~

Comment: `\1` will be `11`, which isn't the same as `22`.

Comment: OK, I got it.Thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the third line:

```
Pattern.matches("(\\d\\d)\\1", "1212")
                 +------+
                    12
```

The [captured group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) is 12. So `\1` contains 12, and since 12 = 12 you get true.

In the fourth line:

```
Pattern.matches("(\\d\\d)\\1", "1122")
                 +------+
                    11
```

The captured group is 11. So `\1` continas 11, and since 11 != 22 you get false.

Comment: I got it~ Thanks for your patient answer.

Answer (score 3):

`\1` is a placeholder for a previous match.
The match for the last example would be "11" 
so \1 turns into "11" which does not match the next two digits "22".

Answer (score 3):

I believe you confused a [*backreference*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) with a [*limiting quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit)

> **Backreferences match the same text as previously matched by a capturing group**.

and

> [There is] an additional **quantifier that allows you to specify how many times a token can be repeated**

So, in order to match 2 occurrences of a grouped subpattern, just use `{2}`:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("(\\d\\d){2}", "1212")); // -->  true  
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("(\\d\\d){2}", "1122")); // -->  true
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/BfdXot)

Or, if these subpatterns are not adjacent, build the pattern dynamically from blocks:

```
String digits = "\\d\\d";
String myRegex = "\\b(?:" + digits + " word|word " + digits + ")\\b";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot~ I didn't completely understand Backreference just before the question. Actually I just want to reuse subpatterns in a regular expression, so the last method you suggested is what I need. But now I'm confused what the question mark after left parentheses does mean? A quantifier?

Comment: No, that is just the beginning of a non-capturing group (`(?:....)`). A group that does not store any submatches in a memory buffer, but just groups several alternatives.

Comment: OK, I found the relative information on the site you referred above. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

`11` !=`22`....
that is wrong with the last one.

`\1` stands for repeated group.Group has `11` so `\1` expects `11` and not `22`.